# Кластерный анализ методом k-means

Tags: r, кластеризация

Здравствуйте. Имеется две случайная величины. Задача попробовать класстеризовать данные с помощью метода k-means. Разбивал на три кластера данные. Результаты меня удивили.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему часть данных, принадлежащая 3 кластеру (синее точки) окружена точками из 2 кластера (зеленные точки)? На картинке это можно увидеть в левом нижнем углу если по-хорошему присмотреться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нормальная ситуация. То есть не совсем нормальная, но данный метод кластеризации иногда приводит к таким странным результатам. Дело в том, что расстояния считаются от центроидов, а не от соседних точек. Подробнее об этом и других нюансах можно почитать по ссылке http://dungba.org/the-strange-effect-of-k-means/

Comment: Здорово! Я прочитаю. Спасибо за полезную информацию. 

Но при следующих инерациях такой эффект может пропасть. То есть k-means классифицирует нормально. Это нормально? То есть я хочу спросить: будет ли в рамках прогонять k-means столько раз сколько потребуется пока не будет дано такое разбиение которое тебя удовлетворит?

Comment: k-means ничего не классифицирует, поскольку не является методом классификации. А кластеры действительно получаются разными при повторных запусках, поэтому считается нормальным повторять процедуру несколько раз. Но если картинки радикально разные, то правильнее не выбирать понравившуюся, а признать, что разделить данные на кластеры таким способом не получилось.